# Database approach for different product types

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

My e-commerce like application has different product/service types listed. Each product/service type has different properties/attributes. For example, a mobile phone would have different attributes like CDMA/GSM and a TV would have different set of attributes like USB/HDMI. Many product types are available in the starting and I will keep on adding different product/service types.

So my question is, should I need to have a different table for each product/service type in my database because each product/service has different attributes (columns) or is there a different, but better approach? Estimated count of product/service types is 50+.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180758/design-parts-db

Comment: OK, so all the common attributes in one table and attributes specific to different product types in their respective tables. This approach looks good. That worked for you?

Comment: Thank you :) And one last thing, if I ever need to add a new attribute for a particular product type, is it fine to add a new column for that in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Your case is an instance of class/subclass or type/subtype.  The buzzphrase in ER modeling is "generalization/specialization".

Here's a list of tags that pertain to questions like yours:

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)
[shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

If you read the tag wiki for these three tags, you'll get some general pointers on designing for the case you outline.  In addition, the questions tagged with those three tags contains answers that will help you.

If you'd like to do a little more research on the web,  I recommend Martin Fowler's web pages where he outlines single table inheritance and class table inheritance.  This covers the basics very well.  If you still want to go deeper, you'll need to consult a textbook.

All of these techniques arise out of the fact that neither the relational data model nor vanilla SQL had any mechanism for providing inheritance to the modeler.